# Jquery 1.9 Select Span Tag in Form

Tags: jquery

I have a callback function that is part of an ajax call to my server.  When the data is returned to the callback the function needs to post the information into a span tag located within the calling form tags.

I know the line is  incorrect but am leaving it there in hopes that it will explain my intent.  I am looking for help finding the syntax to select the span tag from within the form.

```
$form.find("UpdateMessage").replaceWith(data.processingMessage);
```

-

```
var ajaxUpdateWaitTime = function () {
    var $form = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {

        $form.find("UpdateMessage").replaceWith(data.processingMessage);
        $form.children("UpdateMessage").effect('highlight');
    });

    return false;
};
```

Here is the markup if it helps.

```
<input type="button" data-ucw-updateWaitTimeButton="@facility.Id" value="Edit" />
                    <form method="post" action=@Url.Action("UpdateWaitTime", "Facilities") data-ucw-updateWaitTimeForm="@facility.Id" style="display:none" >
                        <input type="hidden" value="@facility.Id" />
                        <input type="text" value="0" style="width:15px" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Update Wait Time" />
                        <span class="UpdateMessage"></span>
                    </form>
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: does the span has any unique identifier like a id or a class? can you post the markup?

Answer (score 0):

After much digging and testing this seems to work.

```
var $formId = $form.attr('id');
var $spanTag = $('form#' + $formId + '> span.updateMsg.updateMsg');
```